# .htaccess for header and footer using PHP

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, include

I know that I can write

```
php_value auto_prepend_file "/root-directory/header.php"
php_value auto_append_file "/root-directory/footer.php"
```

into *.htaccess* to include `header` and `footer` at the top and the end of every single page, but this would put them even before/after `<html>` and `<body>` tags.

It works anyway, but I know that it isn't a good way to set up an html page.

While I can "fix" the problem with the `footer` by putting `</body>` and `</html>` tags at the end of it (even if it isn't such a good thing having every single source code without closing tags), I can't find a way to fix the header.

Is there a way to tell `.htaccess` to put the `header` right after `<body>` tag and the `footer` right before `</body>`?

Comment: Well, your application logic needs to be modified such that it does not send out full html documents but only a snippet, a fraction of a html document. That fraction, not holding the `<html>` & `<body>` and the `</body>` & `</html>` opening and closing tags, can then be embedded in the auto prepended snippets to form a valid html document. I would still consider that a bad practice, but it is possible. The usual approach is _not_ to handle content aspects on the protocol level, but inside your application's logic controller.

Comment: @arkascha so do you mean that I should manually include `header` and `footer` in every page?

Comment: Well, yes and no. Depends on what you actually mean by "manually" and by "every". I do not know your setup and your application. How you create your content. You did not say so in your question. All I stated is that the usual way is to include header and footer sections of a html document inside the application's controller. I cannot get more specific with that little information you give. Maybe you want to use the `edit` button below your question and provide more information: what kind of application logic do you use? What content is it you serve? What structure?

Comment: Alternatively, if you really need to do content handling on the protocol level you could take a look at the substitution feature the apache http server offers. It is a bit more complex to setup but allows to actually _replace_ those preceding and trailing html tags with a header and a footer instead of just adding those. https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_substitute.html

Comment: @arkascha There's not so much to say about my website...

I'm quite a beginner and it is a website hosted on a free domain with 20-30 pages.

Header and footer should be included in every single page (except for PHP only pages but it doesn't matter). What I want to do is including header and footer automatically, so that I don't have to get crazy with all reative paths or adapt absolute paths when I change my host. When I say 'manually' I mean including header and footer using `include ...` in every single page.

Comment: In simple words: do you have an application that uses a controller or not? If yes, see above. If not, then change your html or php pages to _not_ have own preceding and trailing document start and ending tags, as mentioned, then your approach will work. If that is not an option, then take a look at the substitution approach I mentioned.

Comment: @arkascha I don't have any applications or frameworks... But I can't figure out how my approach could work for the header. `mod_substitute` seems to be for substitutions only, how can I implement it?

Comment: You want to substitute the preceding `<html ...><body ...>` with `<html ...><body ...>(here your header)` and `</body></html>` with `(here your footer)</body></html>`. That _is_ a substitution. Not elegant, but if you need to do it on protocol level and cannot modify your "pages" as described (why ever), this might be an option.

Comment: @arkascha "`and cannot modify your "pages" as described (why ever)`" do you mean writing `include` in each of them? Of course I can! I just thought it was a better option centralizing everything. Do you suggest writing `include` instead?

Comment: No, I meant what I wrote before, that you _remove_ the starting document tags `<html...><body...>` and the ending tags `</body></html>`, since those are the ones you explicitly mention yourself that they come into the way when you use your `auto_prepend` approach. Without those tags your "pages" are only snippets / fragments of complete documents and you can add your header and footer the way you currently do to receive a valid and well formed document.

Comment: @arkascha I can do it for the *footer*, but before the *header* there should be an `<head>` containing all meta contents which change depending on the page, so I cannot put the `<head>` tag inside the *header*

Comment: And why can't you put that `<head>` tag and the initial `<html...><body...>` tags inside the _header_ you include?

Comment: @arkascha beacuse the content of the `<head>` tag changes depending on the page in which the *header* is included

Comment: Why can't that `header` logic you want to include consider that? It has the same information as the main "page". But anyway, you certainly know best. So you cannot change the way your pages are created, you cannot use the substitution approach, you do not use the standard of a controller, you do not want to modify your pages. Hard to find a solution then, I'd say.

Comment: @arkascha I can do all these things (except for the controller which I don't know how to use)... I can edit my pages and my header too, the problem is that there's a **single** header for **every page**, so meta tags (which are different in every page) can't be included in a commn header

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of your `header.php` and `footer.php` files containing (what sounds like) raw HTML (or HTML with PHP embedded) you could perhaps assign this content to variables and use the variables inside your HTML page - wherever you want the content to appear. You could call this file `template-variables.php` and then you'd only need one file that you include with `auto_prepend_file`.

For example:

```
php_value auto_prepend_file "/root-directory/template-variables.php"
```

Then in `template-variables.php`:

```
<?php
// Template variables...
// (NB: Using HEREDOC <<< syntax)
$HEADER= <<<EOF
<header>
    <h1>Header goes here</h1>
    <p>More content goes here...</p>
</header>
EOF;

$FOOTER= <<<EOF
<footer>
    <p>Footer content goes here...</p>
    <p>Copyright etc.</p>
</footer>
EOF;
```

In your HTML/PHP document:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- PHP: Short echo format -->
    <?=$HEADER?>

    <p>Some more content goes here...</p>

    <?=$FOOTER?>
</body>
</html>
```

To be a bit more *encapsulated* you could use an associative array to hold your template variables, then you only have one variable in the global namespace. For example:

```
<?php
// Template variables...
$TEMPLATE_VARIABLES = [];
$TEMPLATE_VARIABLES['HEADER'] = 'Hello world';
:
```

You can then easily traverse all your "template variables" in your script if needed.

Comment: Wow! I've never heard of this possibility... Thank you